# Extract text inside anchor tag using xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to ascertain how many pages are there for any search result on a site so that i can scrape data for all the pages using lxml and xpath.

There is a pagination tab with the following structure:
Page: 1 2 3 ... 7 next

the html content for the same being something like

```
<ul class="ulclass">
 <li></li>
 <li>
      <span> You are on the first page</span>
      "1"
 </li>
 <li>
      <a href="link to second page">
        <span></span>
      "2"
      </a>
 </li>
  <li>
 </li>
      ...
  <li>
      <a href="link to last page">
        <span></span>
      "7"
      </a>
 </li>
```

My approach is to extract the page numbers 1,2,3,7 so that i can repeat the web scraping 7 times for every page 'cause otherwise it just scrapes the first result of the page.
I have written the following xpath, but it doesnot return correct page numbers.

> xpath('//ul[@class="ulclass"]/li/a/text())

Comment: If you are doing web-scraping what other software are you working *with*?

Comment: I am not using anything other than python and lxml at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If I expand your example to form this,

```
<ul class="ulclass">
<li><span>You are on the first page</span>"1"</li>
<li><a href="link to second page"><span></span>"2"</a></li>
<li><a href="link to third page"><span></span>"3"</a></li>
<li><a href="link to fourth page"><span></span>"4"</a></li>
<li><a href="link to fifth page"><span></span>"5"</a></li>
<li><a href="link to sixth page"><span></span>"6"</a></li>
<li><a href="link to last page"><span></span>"7"</a></li>
</ul>
```

then using scrapy in Python I can get this:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=open('temp.htm').read())
>>> selector.xpath('..//ul[@class="ulclass"]/li/a/text()').extract()
['"2"', '"3"', '"4"', '"5"', '"6"', '"7"']
```

Comment: Thanks for your turnaround Bill. Deeply appreciate it. The issue was with the webpage. It was returning the last number as some multiple of 7.  xpath was returning same result as yours. :)